BIOS asks password every time but secure boot is disabled
I had to set a temporary password for both SSDs using secure boot but now, I can't disable it. I tried to restore and revert everything, but it doesn't go away.


Here, Admin y User Password only display an input to set a new password.



Password on boot and Secure Boot are two different things. Secure Boot is about how the BIOS/UEFI hands off to the OS, and does not involve a password. Open the individual drive and see if there's a password option there.

How often are you disabling and enabling Secure Boot?

Most firmware will not let you get rid of a password once you have set the password. Most modern firmware passwords also can be reset.

Are you sure that isn't a HDD/SSD password instead of a BIOS password? The CE480Y2D100 is a low priced SSD and the password request seems to be coming from that rather than your firmware. https://www.notebookcheck.net/BiWin-CE480Y2D100-1TB-SSD-Benchmarks.701292.0.html

@Ramhound never. I just had to do it once

@Mokubai what I meant is that I enabled this password from BIOS. The password protects both HDD/SSD. I did nothing related to the OS

@music2myear I searched already there but only let me to change the password. I added another image

@Ramhound "Most firmware will not let you get rid of a password once you have set the password" that's insane. How is that even possible?

Have you confirmed that the prompt (especially the one on the drive-specific page) does not accept empty input as a special value (that disable/uninstall the password)?

That's it, guys! I had to specify a new password and just leave it blank. If you want to leave an answer I'll accept it

Secure Boot is a UEFI function that involves

preventing the loading of UEFI drivers or OS boot loaders that are not signed with an acceptable digital signature.

A Boot Password is a BIOS or UEFI function that

allow(s) you to restrict people from booting the computer, booting from removable devices, and changing BIOS or UEFI settings without your permission.

You are looking at a Boot Password or an HDD password, not anything related to Secure Boot. Your enabling Secure Boot did not add this password, and disabling Secure Boot will not remove this password.
The correct way to "remove" a Boot Password may vary between firmware (BIOS or UEFI) implementations, but generally involves setting the password to an empty value.
